# Html action without referencing a script and referencing a method instead

Tags: php, html

Normally, when I'm handling forms, in the "action" parameter, I usually have to reference a full PHP script, like this:

```
<form method="post" action="foo.php"></form>
```

Is there a way to tell the form to use a function or method rather than having to mention a whole script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perform function on form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046857/perform-function-on-form-submit)

Comment: Are you asking how you would handle a form on the page it's on rather than submitting it to refresh the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of, but I'm pretty sure you could do something like this...

```
action="foo.php?fromForm=yes"
```

Then in your php code, you could have this...

```
if($_GET['fromForm'] == "yes") {
//put your function here, or call it here
}
else {
//rest of code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

imagining that your form looked something like:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>
        <label></label>
        <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label></label>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

then you could just put at the top of the php:

```
if (isset($_POST['textfield'])) {
    foo();
}
```

replacing `foo();` with the name of the function you want to execute.

This simply checks if there was any form data posted to the page with `name="textfield"`.

Comment: This is better IMO. The URL stays clean, and the PHP won't be executed again if someone bookmarks the page, for example.

Answer (score 0):

No. What you're specifying is not a *script*, it's a **URL**. HTML/the browser doesn't know about server-side functions or methods, only about URLs.

Comment: Thanks, needless to say I'm a webdev n00b, so I am not yet familiar with any of the inner-workings. That makes absolute sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onsubmit` attribute to call a javascript method instead:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="doSomething()"></form>
```

You can also use this to validate your form before passing it to a script such as the following:

```
<form method="post" action="foo.php" onsubmit="canSubmit()"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: I'm assuming you're asking if you can access a method or function in the PHP code on the server-side, not call a JavaScript function on the client-side!**

The client side cannot arbitrarily invoke methods on the server side. The URL or path to the resource, is what is used to identify a resource on the server.

If you want to perform different functionality in the same script, you could use if/else blocking and use query parameters to differentiate your URLs.

**HTML:**

```
 <form method="post" action="foo.php?method=saveData"></form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<? /* foo.php */
    if($_REQUEST['method'] == "saveData") {

        // do stuff

    } else if($_REQUEST['method'] == "doSomethingElse") {
        // do other stuff

    }
?>
```

This is at it's core a very basic example. For more complex needs, many frameworks can perform this level of branching, out of the box, and with much more sophistication.

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP script is written as follows:

```
<?php
switch ($_GET ['f']) { 
  case 'do_one':
    // do something
    break;
  case 'do_two':
    // or use a callback
    do_two_callback ();
    break;
  default:
    // ...
}
?>
```

... you can always do this

```
<form method="post" action="foo.php?f=do_one"></form>
```